# Is there a quick way to mark a revert as a fixup?

Tags: git

`git commit` provides a `--fixup` option that allows for easy `--autosquashing` later on. Is there a way to run a `git revert` of a fixup that is also a fixup in one go?

Looking for something like this:

```
* fds7d8d fixup! fixup! Revert "fixup! my commit message"
* dfk3ld8 fixup! Revert "fixup! fixup! my commit message"
* dl2iow8 fixup! fixup! my commit message
* a5bbcba fixup! my commit message
* 3ca1e98 my commit message
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you would call this "easy", but `git revert -n` will do the revert without committing.  You can then run `git commit` and edit the commit message to insert `fixup!` (repeated as much as you care to—repetition doesn't seem to matter, even though it *appears* to be repeated on purpose if you're fixing up a fixup).

(I would not do this myself though: I would just rebase now and pluck out the bad commit.  Then again, I never use autosquash in the first place. :-) )

Comment: Just a tip to others here, that you can do `git commit --fixup HEAD` to commit the revert as a fixup after running `git revert -n <SHA>`.